# Is there a situation where the measurable analog of the fundamental group can be computed and isn't trivial?

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

So this question lingered in my mind for quite some time: Is it possible to develop "algebraic measure theory" analogous to algebraic topology, and can it be useful?

What I mean is the following: Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space, and fix $x_0\in X$. Let $L_{x_0}:=\{\gamma:[0,1]\to X \text{ measurable }|\ \gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=x_0\}$ be the set of measurable loops based at $x_0$ (where $[0,1]$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). Two loops $\gamma_0,\gamma_1\in L_{x_0}$ are said to be 'measure equivalent' if there exists a measurable function $H:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to X$ such that $H(-,i)=\gamma_i$ for $i\in\{0,1\}$, and $H(i,t)=x_0$ for all $i\in\{0,1\}$ and $t\in[0,1]$. We denote measure equivalence by $\sim$. Then with the same proofs as in the beginning of algebraic topology, one can equip $L_{x_0}/\sim$ with a group structure via concatenating loops, i.e. if $[\gamma_0],[\gamma_1]\in L_{x_0}/\sim$ are two classes of loops and $\gamma_0 *\gamma_1$ denotes the concatenation of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, then the operation $[\gamma_0]\cdot[\gamma_1]:=[\gamma_0 *\gamma_1]$ defines a group structure on $L_{x_0}/\sim$.

Are there situations where $L_{x_0}/\sim$ can be computed and it isn't the trivial group? To what extent can one carry out the same proofs as in algebraic topology? And has this been investigated at all?

Comment: The issue is that $H(s,t)=x_0$ if $t>0$ and $H(s,0)=\gamma(s)$ for $t=0$ is measurable, so that $L_{x_0}/\sim$ is always trivial.

Comment: The problem will be that measurable is not enough. Ugly discontinuous things are measurable. I